# Conversion NSString to NSDate. 1 day is lost

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, date

```
NSString *dateString = @"20.10.2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]);
```

My output is:

```
2010-10-19 22:00:00 GMT
```

Why is one day lost?

Answer (score 3):

Probably because your locale specificies that you're in GMT +2.

That means the given date is interpreted as 2010-10-20 **00:00** GMT+2, hence in GMT+0 that's 2010-10-19 **22:00**.

Comment: ok, how can I change this options? my iphone is completely set up for one locale: keyboard, language and calendar are set for the german language.

Comment: @Dopamine: You probably don't want to. Just print the date with your current locale. `[someObject description]` is usually a bad choice to show to a user, because Apple might change it without notice and it's usually used for debugging.

Comment: @Dopamine: If you really want an answer to your question posted in the comments, I'd advise you to create a new question asking specifically how to interpret dates as GMT+0.

Answer (score 1):

You not lost 1 day, but 2 hours. But the display is GMT.
What do you want to do with your date ?
See the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class) to change the output formatter